# How to read MIME format emails pop3

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read automaticly emails from an exchange server, but some of them ar in MIME format and can't read them right, so i need a class or something to decrypt the MIME emails. Dose anyone know how to find wath emails are in MIME format and what emails are normal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [OpenPop.NET](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/) library to help with your task. It has MIME parsing features.

Comment: I'd tryed but I can't connect, it says that the "Server is not available".